# What event is triggered when the Browser Address Bar hides on Android's 4.*?

Tags: javascript, ios, events, mobile-safari

I expected a window.resize event to happen but apparently that is not triggered as in iOS Safari.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily a development question. Apps like Tasker trigger off of events.

Comment: I’d say it’s just scrolling…

Answer (score 1):

the mobile safari address bar seems independent of the actual page. mobile chrome on android fires a resize event which is a bad idea. the concept of resizing a window does not exist on a single-window interface.

Comment: from what i gather, chrome no longer resizes the viewport size when revealing the address bar: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/url-bar-resizing